# Dup deleting original ActiveRecord

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

I have a polymorphic association. Whenever I call .dup method on it and save it to another association, the original one disappears

Example: an user has events. The User and the Event has a polymorphic attribute called Type. When a user creates an event, the type from the User should be assigned to the Event

```
@user = User.find(params[:id])
@event = @user.events.build(event_params)
@event.types = @user.types.dup
```

But when I save the event, the Types from @user dissapear from the database!

Why? Dup should duplicate.

**EDIT**
It seems that DUP is not setting the ActiveRecord ID to nil, so it is updating the ActiveRecord to the Event.

Comment: has_many :types, as: :typable

Comment: Seems that you figured this out. :) You should delete the question then.

Comment: But how do I solve this problem? DUP should be setting the ID to nil. Should be duplicating the record. It's not happening. I still can't solve the problem.

Comment: No, it shouldn't do so. Otherwise it wouldn't be a *duplicate object*, don't you think? It's ruby's dup, not activerecord's. Just reset ID yourself or insert a copy (`Type.build(@type.attributes)` or something along these lines)

Comment: Thanks. Now I'm getting 'Types is invalid' error. Damn =(

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/48777/discussion-between-vitor-subs-and-sergio-tulentsev)